# Testing Somesite CRLF Bugs Hole Using Indy IdMappedPortTCP

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-2007, indy10

I want to create a small tool like CRLF Injection or HTTP header respons splitting. I was successful created thousands NetData pattern (data payload) lists. The NetData pattern like this example:

1. `GET http://somebug.com/ HTTP/1.1[CRLF]Host : somehost.com[CRLF]GET somesite.com HTTP/1.1[CRLF][CRLF]`
2. `GET http://somebug.com/ HTTP/1.1[CRLF]Host : somehost.com[CRLF][CRLF]GET somesitesite.com HTTP/1.1[CRLF][CRLF]`
3. `HEAD http://somebug.com/ HTTP/1.1[CRLF]Host : somehost.com[CRLF]CONNECT somesitesite.com HTTP/1.0[CRLF][CRLF][CRLF][CRLF]`

   `...`

If just one data pattern/data payload, I can write example code like:

```
procedure T_CRLFTest.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  if(Pos('CONNECT',TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).NetData)<>0) then
    TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).NetData := 'GET http://somebug.com/ HTTP/1.1'#13#10'Host : somehost.com'#13#10+TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).NetData+#13#10#13#10
end;
```

The problem is, how to test all data pattern let say over 20,000 lists using `IdMappedPortTCP` with multi threaded technique?

I'm using `Delphi 2007` and `Indy 10`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you expand on what exactly you are stuck with.

Comment: thank for your respon, I'm sorry for my bad english. In simple question, I have thousands list of NetData(data payload) with modified varians. I want to applay my NetData lists to `TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).NetData:=mymodifiednetdatalists` I'm stuk how to make my IdMappedPortTCP1 to applay thousands list using thread. I'm assuming in conventional 1 IdMappedPortTCP1 applay 1 mymodifiednetdatalists, this impossible because I don't want to put thousands IdMappedPortTCP base on mymodifiednetdatalists

Comment: I still don't understand. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`NetData` contains whatever **raw data** was available on the socket at the moment the `OnExecute` event was fired.  There is no guarantee of the content of `NetData` on any given triggering of the event.  So every time the event is triggered, you need to store that data to your own per-connection buffer somewhere, then you can parse that buffer looking for complete lines and tweaking them as needed, then update the `NetData` with new data as needed.  Whatever data is in `NetData` when the event handler exits is the data that gets passed along to the target server.

BTW, `HEAD http://somebug.com/ HTTP/1.1[CRLF]Host : somehost.com[CRLF]CONNECT somesitesite.com HTTP/1.0[CRLF][CRLF][CRLF][CRLF]` is two HTTP commands overlapping each other.  That should never happen in a real scenario.  If it is, then the client that is sending those commands is faulty.

Comment: Hello @Remy, yes maybe "my NetData pattern" it is not a regular http, but I have learning this mechanism for bypassing my ISP, and it work. The `HEAD http://somebug.com/ HTTP/1.1[CRLF]Host : somehost.com[CRLF]CONNECT somesitesite.com HTTP/1.0[CRLF][CRLF][CRLF][CRLF]` it just sample at one list of "my NetData pattern lists". Of course I will not applaying real string that pattern to NetData before replacing the strings. Just give me some code to create IdMappedPortTCP at runtime with 1 NetData from lists with looping until end of lists with my NetData pattern.

Comment: To do what you are asking for, you need to do what I told you. The unpredictable nature of `NetData` makes it impossible to do reliable pattern matching on every single firing of the `OnExecute` event without a buffer to save data between events. You need to buffer all incoming data, and perform pattern matching on that buffer, not on `NetData` itself. Receive some data, add to buffer, check buffer for completed requests. If none is ready, clear `NetData`, otherwise for each request set `NetData` to modified variant if found, otherwise set `NetData` to original request.